# Solaris built in command for TCP connection without all the telnet stuff

Tags: tcp, telnet, utilities

Sometimes `telnet` is used for testing non telnet servers such as HTTP or SMTP servers where the TELNET protocol usually stays out of the way. However, I think I have run into a case where it is in the way while debugging a TCP server. I ran

> telnet localhost  < data_file

And the data the server receives is different than what is in the file.

Is there either an option to telnet or a whole nother command that I can use?

If it has to be installed separately, then I don't want it. I will just do without.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, actually it's called `netcat` and is Not a built-in for Solaris. But you have another option if you use bash or zsh (or may be something else):

man bash:

> ```
> Bash handles several filenames specially when they are  used
> in redirections, as described in the following table:
>   …
>      /dev/tcp/host/port
>           If host is a valid hostname or  Internet  address,
>           and  port  is  an  integer  port number or service
>           name, bash attempts to open a  TCP  connection  to
>           the corresponding socket.
> ```

Comment: That is nice to know about `bash` and `/dev/tcp`. I don't see the capability of a two way connection though, but I expect this will be helpful down the road,, and for the more needy cases, I will just write my own script.

Comment: Excelent!! Rare knowlege

Answer (score 3):

I guess `netcat`? There's a package [here](http://sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#nc). But it isn't provided by Sun default. Do you have something against packages?

Comment: Yes, it is temporary until a new plan is in place for server configuration management. Right now, everything needs to stay put.

Comment: IMHO, a well-documented list of installed packages will work just as well for management purposes. And I would say that the benefit of using the extensive GNU tools that aren't available in a base install on Solaris outweighs the benefits of using a completely base system. But that's definitely your choice to make :)

Answer (score 3):

As poige already said: You can use the /dev/tcp// device. Here is an example:

```
bash-3.2$ cat </dev/null >/dev/tcp/1.2.3.4/22; echo $?
0
bash-3.2$ cat </dev/null >/dev/tcp/1.2.3.4/1522; echo $?
bash: connect: Connection timed out
bash: /dev/tcp/1.2.3.4/1522: Connection timed out
1
```

You probably write a small bash script for this. The "timed out" message appears after TCP timeout which ich mostly set to 4 minutes. That's quite long...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `tcpdump`? But since it is obviously not important...

Comment: I guess your haven't attentively read the question.